# How Can I Do a Fresh Outlook 2016 Install Using Current Outlook Settings and PST Files?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, pop3

I am running Outlook 2016 (365) on a machine running Windows 7 Home.

I am about to restore my laptop's C drive (on an aftermarket SSD desk I installed) to its factory original settings, i.e., reformat my C drive. By doing this, I will be wiping out all the programs I've installed on my machine, including Office 2016, and starting over, as though I'm buying a new laptop. Once I complete the restoration to original settings, I will be reinstalling all the programs I'd run before, including Office.

I know when you install Outlook fresh on a machine, it walks you through creating an IMAP email account and creates a new PST file for it. I want to avoid all that by instead pointing the install to already Outlook and Archive PST accounts existing on another drive. I also want to port over all my existing settings, including the several Gmail accounts I manage through Outlook (which I do as POP3 account s rather than IMAP accounts).

Can anyone advise how I can best prepare for this before I go through the restore process? I.e., what steps should I take to back up mailbox settings in preparation for this undertaking?

Comment: Anyone? ........

Comment: Bueller? ........